# Can not copy files From Azure VM to local Windows

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04

I want to copy file from Azure Linux VM to local Windows PC. Actually I remember, I could do this perfectly with the same command but now when I run the cmd it shows message as 100% done but when I go to `tmp` directory, I dont see the file there.
Here is the cmd I give on Linux VM:

`scp -r mlopenedx@138.91.116.170:/edx/var/log/tracking/tracking.log /tmp/`

And this is output I get:

`tracking.log      100%   70KB  70.0KB/s   00:00`

But when I see `tmp` folder I dont see the file.Can any on suggest me the answer.
I have tried things like: giving Home folder `~/` instead of `/tmp/`.

Also tried below cmd:

`sudo scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa mlopenedx@MillionEdx:/edx/var/log/tracking/tracking.log /tmp/`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to run `pscp` from windows like this:

```
pscp mlopenedx@LINUXVMIP:/edx/var/log/tracking/tracking.log c:/someExistingFolder/tracking.log
```

to have pscp command you need to install `PuTTY`.

your command looks wrong as one of the paths needs to be Windows valid path `C:/Folder/Folder/File.ext`. If you are executing that command from Linux VM and 138.91.116.170 is your Linux vm IP address than you are copping files locally - you can try finding your log file on that linux in `\tmp\` folder. In order for that to work from remote Linux to local Windows you would need public IP for your windows or some sort of tunnel that would allow this connection.

Also you are adding `-r` recursive copy and you are pointing to file.

Comment: Thanks Rafal, Can you tell me the cmd I can use to take the file on local Windows from remote Linux. I tried above cmd but it says: ```Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)```

Comment: You say my cmd will copy file in that Linux VM only. But I have tried the same cmd last time and I got file in my local Windows machine. Don't know why is it not working now?

Comment: Rafal..Any clue on this..Transferring file from Azure VM to Local Windows? I tried AzCopy,but it is not for files on VM. It is for blob, table etc.